# Magento 2: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' ''

Tags: magento2, module, error

This is my first time trying out Magento 2 and I tried creating a basic custom module, but when I tried to execute the `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` it, I got an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''Jurgis_Twilio'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ')' in C:\wamp64\www\magento2\app\code\Jurgis\Twilio\registration.php on line 4

`C:\wamp64\www\magento2\app\code\Jurgis\Twilio\registration.php`:

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Jurgis_Twilio',
    __DIR__
);
```

my php version (`php -v`):

```
PHP 7.0.10 (cli) (built: Aug 18 2016 09:48:53) ( ZTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

Comment: have you craeted `composer.json` file

Comment: hmm, no. The tutorial I was following didn't say anything about that...

Comment: You need to check your custom module basic files and directories proper or not.
and also check module name within code. http://inchoo.net/magento-2/how-to-create-a-basic-module-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot explain this, but the error was fixed by just rearranging the elements in one line like this:

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Jurgis_Twilio', __DIR__);
```

Comment: @ErSarveshVTiwari  :)