# Custom Theme registration.php error in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, theme, registration, custom-theme

I'm using **magento 2.2.5** and  try to create customer theme, I added the **`registration.php`** inside **`app/design/frontend/Test/mine/`**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'frontend/Test/mine',
    __DIR__
);
```

when I ran the **`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`** , I got the following error:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ''frontend/Test/mine''
>       (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ')' in
>       /var/www/project/app/design/frontend/Test/mine/registration.php on
>       line 4

Answer (score 2):

I cannot explain this, but the error was fixed by just rearranging the elements in one line like this:

```
<?php \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register( \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME, 'frontend/Test/mine', __DIR__ );
```

Reference [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/178772/magento-2-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected)

Answer (score 0):

Your component name should be in the format `Vendor_Module`, so in your case that would be `Mine_Theme` instead of `frontend/Test/mine`.